# Optimizing Codes

Tags: vb.net

Please provide some good coding habits that one must follow to optimize vb.net code.

Habits that a newbie must know while coding.

For Example,

*Program to multiply the textbox length by 2 and show it in the message box*

```
Dim a as integer  
Dim b as integer
a = textbox1.length
b = a*2 
Msgbox(b)
```

Better code (maybe)

> Msgbox(2 * textbox1.length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a newbie, then the best thing to do is to learn the truth of Knuth's comment that premature optimization is the root of all evil.  See http://www.stevemcconnell.com/cctune.htm for a detailed version of that advice.

Note that the book that chapter is from was written in the 90s.  But it is a true classic that is as relevant to someone coding in vb.net code today as it was relevant to someone coding in C when it was written.